# Get two nodes of lowest frequency and create parent node for them (Huffman Tree)

Tags: c++, data-structures, visual-studio-2017

I am currently making a huffman tree filled with nodes of characters that are being read from a text file along with the amount of time they appear in the text file (frequency). I have created a vector that holds nodes containing character that is read and the frequency. I have also sorted it so the vector is in descending order and has the Node with the least frequent character at the end.

My problem: I need to get two nodes of lowest frequency and I have started coding this function but don't understand how to call this function twice without my function getting the value of the last node twice.

Desired outcome: To be able to call my function twice and create a parent node like in my code below.

Function I am working on to call twice and get the node with lowest frequency:

```
Node * getLeastFrequencyNode(vector<Node *> & v) {
    Node * leastfreq = v[0]; 
    for (unsigned i = 1; i < v.size(); i++) {
        if ((v[i]->freq) < (leastfreq->freq)) {
            leastfreq = v[i];
        }
    }
    return leastfreq;   
}
```

How I want to be able to call my function given one node is:

```
struct Node {
    Node * left;
    char ch;
    unsigned long long freq;
    Node * right;
};



// Get 2 nodes with least frequency
Node* left = getLeastFrequencyNode(v);
Node * right = getLeastFrequencyNode(v);

Node * parent = getNode(-1, left->freq + right->freq);
```

Comment: If you already have it sorted do you really need this function? Isn't v[v.size()-1] and v[v.size()-2] the 2 nodes you want?

Comment: You are absolutely right lol thank you